# How do I encrypt and E-Mail the entered data in my multiple page jQuery form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

If you want to view an example of the script I'm using with all the questions I'd be using visit here: http://mysetforadvisors.simplyjordan.net/custom/

Here is the original script I downloaded: http://ivanvillareal.com/development/dynamic-multi-form-on-same-page-with-jquery-and-php/

What I want to do is encrypt all the data the user enters and either submit the data to a database that can be viewed through an admin control panel or E-mail the data to an admin email in an organized fashion.

If you want to view the code online, you can check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/JordanSimps/Multi-page-Form

Comment: Stop. Don't pass go. You're opening a can of worms you DON'T want to deal with if you don't know EXACTLY what you're doing. For the CC part, consider a thrid party such as https://stripe.com/

Comment: Encryption is an insanely difficult thing to get right. [Schneier's Law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): `Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.`. You need find a library that's written by _professionals_, has been around for a few years and has been reviewed multiple times. Anything less will offer no guarantee of security against anyone other than a casual observer.

Comment: @Basic Could I just make it email all the inserted information instead of storing the information on my server? Would that be secure enough?

Comment: Too long for a comment, one minute

Answer (score 0):

From my comments on the OP...

Encryption is an insanely difficult thing to get right.

Schneier's Law:

> Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

You need find a library that's written by professionals, has been around for a few years and has been reviewed multiple times. Anything less will offer no guarantee of security against anyone other than a casual observer

**Re: "Could I just make it email all the inserted information"**

Unfortunately not...

Emails can be considered as secure as postcards. The message (in plain text) is passed down a line of servers controlled by 3rd parties. Any one of them could see your email (and most of them keep copies for at least a short time to allow re-sending in case of problems). You could potentially us GPG/PGP or similar but they're a bit fiddly to get working well (IMHO).

The best thing you can do to be secure in Javascript is to open an `https://` connection and then `POST` the data. This provides the same security as (say) internet banking assuming you get the right certificate.

That said, you may run into issues due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) depending on where your code is deployed. In short, JS can only communicate with the domain it was initially loaded from. There's [a way around this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).